# Inserting data into entire range of excel sheet from delimited file

Tags: excel, vba

We are working on a job which needs data to be inserted into an excel sheet from a delimited text file. The code is ready and working, but it inserts data cell by cell making it a very slow process. Please suggest a method to insert data into the entire range at one go, which should make the operation faster.

find the code snippet below.

```
    Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
        WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    ColNdx = SaveColNdx
    Pos = 1
    NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    While NextPos >= 1
        TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
        Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = TempVal
        Pos = NextPos + 1
        ColNdx = ColNdx + 1
        NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    Wend
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just opening the delimited file in Excel as a csv/txt file: thats fast. 
 Or you could create and populate a 2 dimensional variant array cell by cell, and then assign the variant array to the Excel range. That will be  much faster because it minimises the object model overhead.

Comment: + 1 :) I am more inclined to your first suggestion. Opening the text file using Excel directly. That would be very fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just open the csv file (or variant) as is in Excel

The code below imports each line as a variant array and then dumps row by row to Excel. I probably should have gone a step further and dumped each row array to a single combined array before entering the data to Excel but I went this way as I am unclear as to why you are ignoring a single overall input

Also, I think these lines are redundant, as it simply adds a blank "record" to the rightmost cell.

```
 If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then    
 WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep   
 End If
```

**Main Code**

```
Sub Test()

Dim fName As String
Dim Sep As String
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim aRRSplit()

fName = "c:\test.csv"
Sep = ","

Open fName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    If Right$(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
        WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    aRRSplit = Application.Transpose(Split(WholeLine, Sep))
    lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
    Cells(lngCnt, 1).Resize(1, UBound(aRRSplit)) = Application.Transpose(aRRSplit)
Wend
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I found online which works quickly for me.

```
Function doFileQuery(fileName As String, outSheet As String) As Boolean

Dim rootDir As String

rootDir = "W:\Development"

Dim connectionName As String

connectionName = "TEXT;" + rootDir + "\" + fileName

With Worksheets(outSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connectionName, Destination:=Worksheets(outSheet).Range("A5"))

    .Name = fileName
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
doFileQuery = True
End Function
```

Hope this helps!